# Should tag wikis contain product version infomation?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I came across the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wildfly/info) for WildFly today.  At the bottom, it has the following:

```
## Version information

 - Current *Release* version: **x.x.x**
```

where x.x.x is a valid version.

Here's the problem.  When I saw it this morning, it said 12.0.0.Final.  But the current version is 16.0.0.Final.  In fact the project appears to be dropping new releases every three months.  But judging from the history, this tag wiki only seems to get attention about once a year.  That means that the "current" release information is *typically* incorrect.

Is it a good idea to have a current release number in a tag wiki if the tag wiki is going to languish?

Or to generalize, if the purpose of tag wikis is to provide basic definitive information, then should there be general advice to tag wiki authors / editors to avoid putting ephemeral information into the wiki?

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed this several times, particularly with people submitting largely-pointless edits to tag wikis that do nothing but update the current version number. I don't understand why having that information there makes sense.

Answer (score 13):

**No**, current version/release numbers do not belong in a tag wiki, whether the tag is languishing or not.

The tag wiki provides a quick overview of the tag and its usage.  A line listing the current release numbers is too specific.

It will also be out of date at times, since there will always be a gap between any new release and a possible update of the tag with the new number (which can take several days, particularly if the wiki edit needs approval).  If minor bug fix releases are frequent enough (only updating the third or fourth number), this cycle may even lag behind a version number of two.

When these current numbers don't get updated for a while that can lead to possible confusion (OK, we're assuming the tag wiki is actually being read).  If I'm using version "14.0.0" and the tag wiki says the current version is "12.0.0", am I using the right tag?  Is there a different name?  Do questions about this version (14.0.0) even belong here?

Answer (score 4):

The tag wiki can be kept entirely up-to-date while still helping to provide version information by linking to WildFly's [downloads page](https://wildfly.org/downloads/) and not mentioning a specific number in the wiki itself.

Either linking to a list on a product's official site or the Wikipedia article (if said article is being well-maintained) will work for most products.

---

I doubt that a warning would be effective at stopping poor editing. The best that we can do is to carefully review these edits and also to occasionally review tag wikis to make sure that they're the best they can be.

Comment: You are probably correct about a warning not stopping poor edits.  However, such guidance (or even this Q&A) could be used as the basis for "nuke on site" for out-of-date release info in tag wikis.  (Alternatively replacing with a link to a definitive source works for me.)  I'm seeing a consensus that that kind of info is harmful if people are not keeping it up-to-date.